# Pre-fill form on Javascript site

Tags: javascript, html, url

Hi guys please could you help me  I want to pre-fill the Centre part of the form on this website

https://bt.learnmyway.com/user#!/register

So that once a user goes on it the centre is pre-populated, the centre to be populated with is Azalea Academy Community interest company or centre ID 8008530

I tried to look at  view source but not sure what the name of the variable is and its not responding when I use #centre_id=8008530 at the end?

Would really appreciate the help

Thanks

Comment: I have no access to the website coding so needs to be on the url client side

Comment: Please clarify your problem. What you're exactly trying to do?

Comment: Also you can't call it a "JavaScript site". Every website is composed of HTML, javascript, CSS and often PHP.

Comment: HI Marshmallow thanks for getting back to me, I want the website to pre-populate the centre field of the register form by adding the centre in the URL I hope that clarifies things?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:
Since the website runs on jquery, this code gets the Id of the form input and puts a value to it, but of course you can clearly do this manually, but here is the code: Just open developer tools, and on the console type this:

```
$('#centre_id').val(8008530);
```

or

```
$('#centre_id').val('Azalea Academy Community Interest company');
```

Or replace with whatever value you'd like inside `val()`

And of course this will only last until you reload the page, because you are only changing what's in your browser, not the code being received from the server

Comment: Hi Thank you so much sorry I have no access to the website coding so needs to be on the url client side was not sure how to add that to the question made a comment below it

Comment: I have a cookie on my browser so its pre-populated for me but I want to add the centre id in the url so that its prepopulated even when I new user goes in the site

Comment: The only way for you to affect that input field from the URL is through Javascript injection in the browser.Replace this code with the url of the website and click Enter: ```javascript:$('#centre_id').val('My value here')```, NOTE: As per your question, this cannot be appended to the url because it will not work ... So the method you are trying to simulate by having a predefined url to fill that input field will not work, unless you were to change the value of that cookie which fills that input field by default